# Can I rewrite this expression as a Kronecker product?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, and let $a > 0$ be a given constant.
Let $\text{vec}(\cdot)$ denote the operator that stacks vertically the columns of a $d \times d$ matrix into a $d^2 \times 1$ vector.
Does there exists a matrix $S$ such that

$$
\text{vec}(M) \text{vec}(M)^{\top} + a \, (M \otimes M) = S \otimes S
$$
?

Comment: No such $S$ exists even if $d = 2$ and $M = I$ is the identity matrix. A necessary criterion for the existence of such an $S$ is that each block of the matrix you wrote on the left-hand-side is a multiple of each other, and that criterion fails in this case.

Answer (score 2):

@Nathaniel Johnston already answered in comments. On a more general note, detecting whether a matrix is a sum of $r$ Kronecker products is essentially the same problem (up to a permutation of the entries) as determining whether a matrix has rank $r$.

Indeed, given a matrix $M\in\mathbb{F}^{am \times bn}$ (divided into blocks $M_{ij}$ each of size $m\times n$), rearrange its entries to form a matrix $N\in\mathbb{F}^{mn \times ab}$ such that each column of $N$ is the vectorization of a block $M_{ij}$; then a rank-$r$ decomposition of $N = u_1 v_1^T + \dots + u_r v_r^T$ corresponds to a decomposition of $M$ as sum of $r$ Kronecker products $M = \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(v_1) \otimes \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(u_1) + \dots + M = \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(v_r) \otimes \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(u_r)$.

Comment: What if $a\to \infty$.
Can we find a matrix $S_a$ such that
$$\text{vec}(M) \text{vec}(M)^{\top} + a (M \otimes M) = a  \, (S_a \otimes S_a)$$ ?

Comment: @FrédéricOuimet - I'm not sure what would qualify as an answer as $a \rightarrow \infty$ really, but this fails for every single $a > 0$ for the exact same reason that has been given. The term on the right has "rank" (in a slightly unusual sense) 1, while the term on the left has "rank" at least 3.

Comment: it means, does it hold asymptotically as $a \to \infty$.
We could have $S_a = M + a^{-1/2} \text{*** something ***} + O(a^{-1})$.
No ?

Comment: Bit it fails no matter what $S_a$ is.

Comment: $1/x = 0$ for no $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but yet we do have the equality in the limit $x\to \infty$.
Similarly, I'm looking for $S_a$ for which the equality above is approximately true and true in the limit $a\to \infty$. Is there really no way to do this ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly now, you're basically asking if you can approximate a rank-3 matrix by a rank-1 matrix, and the answer is still no---a limit of rank 1 matrices is still rank 1.

Comment: what do you mean rank 1?
why would $S_a$ have rank 1 ??

Comment: the first term of $S_a$ for which the equation above would hold asymptotically must be $M$, which has full rank.
I'm looking for some expansion of the form $S_a = M + (...) a^{-1/2} + (...) a^{-1} + (...)$.

Comment: @Frederic -- I'm talking about the weird notion of "Kronecker" rank. The minimal number of terms of the form $A \otimes B$ needed in a sum to represent a given matrix, which is just the usual rank of a certain other matrix with the same entries in a different order. The matrix $\mathrm{vec}(M)\mathrm{vec}(M)^T$ has "Kronecker" rank equal to $4$ in many cases. So you can't just use two other rank-1 ($M \otimes M$ and $S \otimes S$) terms to approximate it, no matter what $M$ and $S$ are.

Comment: Ok, I see n ow.